# TCA displayCond - check if specific value in specific select box is set

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have defined a select like this in the TCA file of my model:

```
    'test' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'test',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'items' => array(
                array("A", "A"),
                array("Foo", "FOO"),
        ...
```

The input field `format` should only appear in the backend, if the option "Foo" is selected.

Attempt 1:

```
    'format' => array(
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:test.config.items:=:Foo',
    ...
```

Attempt 2:

```
    'format' => array(
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:test:=:Foo',
    ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempt 2 looks correct to me. Did you add `'requestUpdate' => 'test'` to the ['ctrl'] section of the TCA to make the form reload after changing the field "test"?

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html?highlight=requestupdate#requestupdate

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I just added it to the ['ctrl'] section of the TCA configuration, after selecting `Foo` I get a pop up which says that it needs to reload the page. But after reload, `format` is still not visible.

Comment: It works now, in the real setting I used `array("Format", "FORMAT")`. I had to correct it to `array("Format", "Format")`... Next time I use the real data if I ask a question, sorry.